# Apllication Icon is Showing correctly in TaskBar but Missing in Start Menu

Tags: c#, .net

I have added application Icon, both in application properties and form properties. When I publish the application icon, it show correctly in TaskBar and in form border. But application icon is not showing in start Menu.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, does the icon appear on the designer?

Comment: Yes. it appear on designer.

Comment: That means you only set the main form icon but forgot application icon is project settings.

Comment: i have set icon in project settings, but it's still not appearing in Start menu.